# Does $\cap_{\eta>\frac{1}{k}} A_\eta$ get "closer" to $\cap_{\eta> 0} A_\eta$ as $k\to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $A_\eta \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact, suppose $\cap_{\eta >0}A_{\eta} = A_0$. Is it true that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $\cap_{\eta >\delta} A_{\eta}$ can be covered by $\cup_{s\in A_0} B_{\epsilon}(s)$?

My feeling is that this isn't true. A necessary and sufficient condition for the statement to be true seems to be the following: for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for all $x\in \cap_{\eta > \delta} A_{\eta}$,
$$\inf_{y\in A_0} d(x, y)< \epsilon. $$

However, this is saying that the intersection of the sets must get uniformly closer to $A_0$. This seems wrong to me. However, I have struggled to produce a counter example using this approach. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This is indeed true. You can prove it by contradiction: suppose there exists $\epsilon$ s.t. for any $\delta=1/n$ it's not covered, choose a point $x_n$ not covered, blah blah blah. You might also be interested in Hausdorff metric